# Eclipse Content Assist insert/apply suggestion on typing

Tags: eclipse

In the Eclipse Java editor, Content Assist always worked for me like this:

1. Start typing variable name
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> - a list of suggestions appears, the correct one is highlighted
3. Press <kbd>.</kbd> - the highlighted suggestion is inserted and a new suggestion popup appears, showing members/methods for this variable.

Just now, I upgraded to 4.5 (Mars) and now step 3 does not work any more: Instead of pressing <kbd>.</kbd> and just continuing typing, I have to press <kbd>return</kbd>. Nowhere in the preferences (Java / Editor / Content Assist) does there seem to be a setting to change this.

What do I have to do to go back to the old behavior?